# Why can't any browser understand this link? (exept firefox)

Tags: browser, hyperlink

Hy people. I'm working on my webapp for the iphone. On some point you have the option to get a particular document from our appserver. It works on firefox, but safari just shows an empty download window. IE also can't get the file.

Below is the example link.

Is there something wrong with a link of this kind that Safari can't see?

http://192.168.200.32:9999/USER_STORAGE?user=bt&token=bEVfjg%2FGHoHHU2CxmAWyiTXFUgN9kN2o8pEKgCFV5Fw%3D&nonce=9jJgj4qGXB4U7m%2FJXjjsmbfreH2J2nT8D789jHY6zro%3D&parent_session=cjDEN3PvltsAqjiagynS8mN6HKeAgqWv82WJqxWiXD8%3D&method=download&filename=Testdokument2

Comment: That's an internal URL, isn't it?

Comment: Your URL contains a session id. Simply pasting the link between browsers is not going to work unless you create a new session with a new session id in each browser (and thus get a new URL).

Comment: @Álvaro: It may well be, but as long as the iPhone's (or whatever he's testing on) on his LAN (e.g., via WiFi)...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder What I mean is that we cannot have a look at the resource and see what's wrong with it

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: indeed. But probably, the answer lies in a particular HTTP header like Content-Disposition or the like. And without being able to access it, it's pretty difficult to know why firefox behaves differently

Comment: @Álvaro: Ah, I understand. I didn't / don't get that he was asking us to, just asking us if the *link* looked right (not what it linked to).

Comment: @divo but he says it works in firefox

Comment: Internal URL yes. I have an application server on my computer. Client (webapp) authenticates trough the appserver using cookie mehanism. IP and PORT are always the same on my machine (wich contains: database & appserver & webapp)

I mainly use Safari when creating a new session for my webapp and it's also the first browser to test - wich fails to get the file. But afterwards i just copy the link into firefox and ...it gets it!?

Comment: Yes, i knew you would get the actual file i just wanted to know if there's is something wrong? 
I'll ask the guy next door wich holds all the application server logic..maybe he could ceck out that HTTP header you mentioned above.?.. thx alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org) points out that you need to escape those ampersands. We mostly get away not escaping them, but who knows, maybe that's the issue. So:

```
http://192.168.200.32:9999/USER_STORAGE?user=bt&amp;token=bEVfjg%2FGHoHHU2CxmAWyiTXFUgN9kN2o8pEKgCFV5Fw%3D&amp;nonce=9jJgj4qGXB4U7m%2FJXjjsmbfreH2J2nT8D789jHY6zro%3D&amp;parent_session=cjDEN3PvltsAqjiagynS8mN6HKeAgqWv82WJqxWiXD8%3D&amp;method=download&amp;filename=Testdokument2
```

..although I tested those params unescaped and they worked fine on IE7, IE8, Chrome4, Safari4, and Firefox3.6 on Windows. (See test page below)

If that's not it:

- Are you testing it by navigating to that point in the desired browser, rather than copy-and-paste? (E.g., does the session mechanism rely on a cookie, or disregard attempts from a different user agent, or...?)
- If there are cookies involved, does this link use a different port from the response that set the cookie?

My unescaped test page, worked as expected despite being invalid:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body><div>
<a href='showparams.jsp?user=bt&token=bEVfjg%2FGHoHHU2CxmAWyiTXFUgN9kN2o8pEKgCFV5Fw%3D&nonce=9jJgj4qGXB4U7m%2FJXjjsmbfreH2J2nT8D789jHY6zro%3D&parent_session=cjDEN3PvltsAqjiagynS8mN6HKeAgqWv82WJqxWiXD8%3D&method=download&filename=Testdokument2' target='_blank'>the link</a>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Escaped test page, also worked as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
   font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body><div>
<a href='showparams.jsp?user=bt&amp;token=bEVfjg%2FGHoHHU2CxmAWyiTXFUgN9kN2o8pEKgCFV5Fw%3D&amp;nonce=9jJgj4qGXB4U7m%2FJXjjsmbfreH2J2nT8D789jHY6zro%3D&amp;parent_session=cjDEN3PvltsAqjiagynS8mN6HKeAgqWv82WJqxWiXD8%3D&amp;method=download&amp;filename=Testdokument2' target='_blank'>the link</a>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: done it both. First using safari, authenticating (creating session), then browsing to the documents menu, parsing the documents correct, and then getting the URL for a particular document using a GET request with the ID of the document (very simple).

Comment: No, it seems like the URL hasn't changed. The same it is. I've done some testing, writing the file in the html body, showing it inside the URL and using our internt RPCtester wich also show the same URL, wich Firefox when copy&pasted shows correct (popup window with option: download, view). Safari & IE does not show correct

Comment: @Johua: It sounds to me like the *link* is fine, then, and as Victor Jalencas suggested the problem lies not in the link but in the request or response. If it's of any help, the `Content-Disposition` response header I've used successfully with all of the browsers above to trigger a download dialog (rather than opening in a window) is `attachment; filename=foo.pdf` (or whatever the filename is). Similarly, when suggesting opening the document in the browser window instead, `inline; filename=foo.pdf` has worked for me.

Comment: Thx alot, i've got some goog information and will first need to debug & test. If it remains unsolved i will post some more detailed info.

Comment: Hy i'm back to response. Well :( it didn't work.  Here is wat i got:

The url now opens a dialog box asking you to open OR save the file (pdf,word,..etc). But when i actually want to save OR view the file i get a "connection was lost" ERROR. This happens for all browsers. 

Strange, but when i copy the URL directly from my XML file -> it works. 

So I think, that something happens from XML to WebBrowser.

Comment: @Johua: It sounds like a problem on the server side to me, FWIW.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder: THX! Is there a button or something to rate you for the help? Cause i'm relative new here and don't see anything pointing to a "this answers the question"...

Comment: @Johua: Glad that helped. When you see good questions or good answers (even to other peoples' questions), you can click the up arrow next to it to vote it up. That awards some reputation to the person who posted it. Separately, on your own questions, if one of the answers is the right answer, you can click the checkmark next to it, which means you've "accepted" the answer. That also awards some rep to the person who answered. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Hy i'm very blind for finding those things,..i'm looking and looking but don't see any checkmark next to your awnsers,...i'll check it up in the morning (gmt+1).

Comment: @Johua: At the very top of my answer, to the left, there's an up-arrow, a number ("1" as I write this, it may change), and a down-arrow. Underneath the down-arrow is a check mark. That's what you click.

Comment: checked. voteup requires 15 reputation..so that i could not. Anyway..see ya :)

Comment: @Johua: Doh! Hadn't thought of that. :-)